# captureVisibleTab returning undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webpage-screenshot

`captureVisibleTab` [[docs]](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-captureVisibleTab) doesn't appear to be working for me in my Google Chrome extension, I've been trying to get it running in a browser action based extension but the image returned is `undefined` every time.  I then downloaded [the example created by Google](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:screenshot) and this also doesn't appear to work, returning either `undefined` or `white.png` (a blank white image) as the image `src`.

I've tried setting permissions to `"tabs", "<all_urls>"` in the `manifest.json` files for both projects.  I have Google Chrome 37.

I've been trying to find an answer but I don't see any solid information out there, is there a bug, and is there a fix for it?  If there's no fix are there any alternatives?

Thanks, Christian.

Edit:  I should probably make this part more clear. I downloaded the Google example, installed it, ran the extension on code.google.com, and a blank image was returned [see screenshot](http://i.gyazo.com/95fac848d9627330a2a5cd8bcd31cf1e.png).

Comment: To clarify: you downloaded and installed the Google sample application, tested it on a page on `code.google.com` and it produced a blank image?

Comment: That is correct, yes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two bugs at play here:

1. `chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab` requires the `<all_urls>` permission ([crbug.com/339703](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=339703)).
2. `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` is never triggered for extension pages in newly opened extension tabs ([crbug.com/411225](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=411225)).

The work-around for the first bug is to declare `<all_urls>` in the permissions section of the manifest file; the work-around for the second bug is to not use the `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` event to detect whether a tab is updated, but use [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) or [`chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getBackgroundPage) to get the data-URL of the screenshot in the newly opened extension page. (note that you cannot use the webNavigation instead of the tabs API to detect new tabs, because [chrome-extension:-URLs are hidden from the webNavigation API](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=326768)).

Comment: Ahh, I see, a combination of bugs caught me out.  Working now, thanks for the help!